# Compilation error while passing double pointer in cpp

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

void f(char **x)
{
    (*x)++;
    **x = 'a';
}    

int main()
{
    char str[]="hello";
    f(&str);
    cout << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Please tell me why this program is giving compilation Error.I am using the g++ compiler

```
Error :temp1.cpp:16:8: error: cannot convert ‘char (*)[6]’ to ‘char**’ for 
       argument ‘1’ to ‘void f(char**)’
```

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. You're passing a pointer to an array.

Comment: You forgot to include the error message in your post.

Comment: Replace char str[] by char* str and get segmentation fault in f...

Comment: `str` is a constant pointer but the `f` function takes a pointer to a pointer

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `(*x)++;`? You'd have to use an actual pointer for that, since `*x` is an array: `char *p = *x; p++; *p = 'a';`

Comment: You tagged this question with `c++`. Why not just use std::string and references instead of this pointer/array crap?

Comment: why don't you use `std::string`? It's easier to handle and it's implementation is very fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays can be implicitly converted to pointers, but **that doesn't mean that the implicit "pointer equivalent" already exists.**

You are hoping that `f(&str);` will implicitly create both a pointer to `str` **and** a pointer to that pointer.

This small (working) change illustrates this point:

```
int main()
{
    char str[]="hello";
    char *pstr = str;        // Now the pointer extists...
    f(&pstr);                // ...and can have an address
    cout << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing pointer of constant char to the function but in function you are taking it as pointer of pointers. That is the problem. I commented out below where the problem lies. 
*[Off topic but N. B. : Arrays and pointers are different concept.]*

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

void f(char **x)  //**x is pointer of pointer
{
    (*x)++;
    **x = 'a';
}    

int main()
{
    char str[]="hello";
    f(&str); //You are passing pointer of constant char.
    cout << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to run into a serious problem with your function `f` since `&str` and `&str[0]` both evaluate to the same value ... as other posters have pointed out, these operations point to different *types*, but the actual pointer r-value will be the same.  Thus in `f` when you attempt to double-dereference the `char**` pointer `x`, you're going to get a segfault even if you attempted something like a cast to massage the type differences and allow compilation to happen with errors.  This is because you are never getting a pointer-to-pointer ... the fact that `&str` and `&str[0]` evaluate to the same pointer value means that a double-dereference acually attempts to use the `char` value in `str[0]` as a pointer value, which won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're treating arrays as pointers, when they're not. Arrays **decay** into pointers, and in this case, it doesn't. What you're passing in is a `char (*)[6]` when it expects a `char **`. Those are obviously not the same.

Change your parameter to `char (*x)[6]` (or use a template with a size parameter):

```
template <std::size_t N>
void f(char (*x)[N])
```

Once inside, you try to increment what x is pointing to. You can't increment an array, so use an actual pointer instead:

```
char *p = *x;
p++;
*p = 'a';
```

All put together, ([sample](http://liveworkspace.org/code/dee3619f880e88dd92f0b7be7a98b5cf))

```
template <std::size_t N>
void f(char(*x)[N])
{
    if (N < 2) //so we don't run out of bounds
        return;

    char *p = *x;
    p++;
    *p = 'a';
}
```